# Backbone JS - View not rendering

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to get a simple html page to display the retrieved collection data on the html page. There are no errors being thrown so I cannot tell what I'm doing wrong.

The model, collection, and view are being created properly as I can see them in the console with the data that's being retrieved from the API, however the page is not displaying anything on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Model**

```js
Department = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "dept_id",
  urlRoot: appRouteUrl + '/api/v1/departments',
  defaults: {
    dept_code: '',
    dept_desc: ''
  }
});
```

**Collection**

```js
DepartmentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: appRouteUrl + '/api/v1/departments',
  model: Department
});
```

**View**

```js
var DepartmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: "#department-list-template",
  tagName: "ul",
  render: function() {
    var results = [];
    var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.template);
    this.collection.each(function(department) {
      console.log(department);
      var html = compiledTemplate(department.toJSON());
      results.push(html);
    });
    this.$el.html(results);
    return this;
  }
});
```

**Index**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>AppName</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="departments">
    <script type="text/template" id="department-list-template">
      <span><%= dept_desc %></span>
    </script>
  </div>
  <script>
    var departments = new DepartmentCollection();
    departments.fetch();

    var departmentList = new DepartmentListView({
      collection: departments
    });

    $('.departments').html(departmentList.render().$el);
    departmentList.render();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have an item view, I think it's best to iterate on the collection view's template. Make sure you create the view instance/call it's render after your collections fetch method succeeds.

Also, you shouldn't add your template inside an element that can be removed.

```js
Department = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "dept_id",
  defaults: {
    dept_code: '',
    dept_desc: ''
  }
});

DepartmentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Department
});

var DepartmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#department-list-template').html()),
  tagName: "ul",
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      departments: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
var departments = new DepartmentCollection([{
  dept_id: 1,
  dept_code: 'test1',
  dept_desc: 'test1'
}, {
  dept_id: 2,
  dept_code: 'test2',
  dept_desc: 'test2'
}]);

/*
departments.fetch({
  success: function(){
    // render the view here
  }
});
*/

var departmentList = new DepartmentListView({
  collection: departments
});

$('.departments').html(departmentList.render().$el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div class="departments"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="department-list-template">
  <% _.each(departments,function(deparment){ %>
    <li><span><%= deparment.dept_desc %></span></li>
  <% }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but that isn't returning anything either, no errors, but nothing on the screen either. I think i'm going to try and attack this using a different technique.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the render before the ajax call is finished. just use deferred and call render when fetch is finished.

Try changing html this way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AppName</title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/template" id="department-list-template">
    <li><%= dept_desc %></li>
</script>


<div class="departments">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var departments = new DepartmentCollection();

  var departmentList = new DepartmentListView({
    collection: departments
  });
  $.when(departments.fetch()).then(function () {
     $('.departments').html(departmentList.render().$el);
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the view

```
var DepartmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#department-list-template').html()),
        tagName: "ul",


        render: function () {
            var results = [];

            var self = this;
            this.collection.each(function (department) {
                console.log(department);
                var html = self.template(department.toJSON());
                results.push(html);
            });

            this.$el.html(results);

            return this;
        }

    });
```

Comment: When i do the above, I get the following displayed on the page;  #department-list-template#department-list-template

Comment: try use this      $('.departments').html(departmentList.render().el);

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore template function accepts an html string, but you're giving it an id string. Try

```
var DepartmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#department-list-template').html()),


  tagName: "ul",

  render: function(){
    var results = [];

    this.collection.each(function(department){
    var html = this.template(department.toJSON());
    results.push(html);
    });

    this.$el.html(results);

    return this;
  }

});
```

EDIT: using the correct context

```
render: function(){
    var results = [];
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(function(department){
    var html = self.template(department.toJSON());
    results.push(html);
    });

    this.$el.html(results);

    return this;
  }
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion above but that throws dept_list_view.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: this.template is not a function

Comment: Yes, i realize now because in `each` the context is not the view anymore. Try my edit

Comment: Still getting an error; dept_list_view.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: self.template is not a function